# 401 Unauthorized when making request to Azure Mobile Service

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-mobile-services

I have an Azure Mobile service which I am using for authentication. I have a custom auth provider which, once validated, returns the following information:

```
JwtSecurityToken token = AppServiceLoginHandler.CreateToken(claims, signingKey, audience, issuer, null);
return Ok(new LoginResult()
{
  AuthenticationToken = token.RawData,
  User = signinedInUser,
  StatusCode = System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK
});
```

Notice the `Timespan` is set to `null` so the token doesn’t expire.

I then make a subsequent request to my AMS which has a controller protected with the `Authorize()` attribute. However, these are all failing with a `401 Unauthorized` response before any of my breakpoints are being hit.

I can see from the Azure logs where this is happening:

> 2017-10-05T12:18:54  PID[5524] Information Request, Method=POST,
>   Url=https://mywebsite.azurewebsites.net/api/userinfo/update,
>   Message='https://mywebsite.azurewebsites.net/api/userinfo/update'
>
> 2017-10-05T12:18:54  PID[5524] Information Message='UserInfo',
>   Operation=DefaultHttpControllerSelector.SelectController
>
> 2017-10-05T12:18:54  PID[5524] Information
>   Message='MyAMS.Controllers.UserInfoController',
>   Operation=DefaultHttpControllerActivator.Create
>
> 2017-10-05T12:18:54  PID[5524] Information
>   Message='MyAMS.Controllers.UserInfoController',
>   Operation=HttpControllerDescriptor.CreateController
>
> 2017-10-05T12:18:54  PID[5524] Information Message='Selected action
>   'Update(User cpUser)'',
>   Operation=ApiControllerActionSelector.SelectAction
>
> 2017-10-05T12:18:54  PID[5524] Information Message='Will use same
>   'JsonMediaTypeFormatter' formatter',
>   Operation=JsonMediaTypeFormatter.GetPerRequestFormatterInstance
>
> 2017-10-05T12:18:54  PID[5524] Information Message='Selected
>   formatter='JsonMediaTypeFormatter', content-type='application/json;
>   charset=utf-8'', Operation=DefaultContentNegotiator.Negotiate
>
> 2017-10-05T12:18:54  PID[5524] Information
>   Operation=AuthorizeAttribute.OnAuthorizationAsync, Status=401
>   (Unauthorized)
>
> 2017-10-05T12:18:54  PID[5524] Information
>   Operation=UserInfoController.ExecuteAsync, Status=401 (Unauthorized)
>
> 2017-10-05T12:18:54  PID[5524] Information Response, Status=401
>   (Unauthorized), Method=POST,
>   Url=https://mywebsite.azurewebsites.net/api/userinfo/update,
>   Message='Content-type='application/json; charset=utf-8',
>   content-length=unknown'

You can see that the Authorize attribute is setting a 401 response:

> 2017-10-05T12:18:54  PID[5524] Information
>   Operation=AuthorizeAttribute.OnAuthorizationAsync, Status=401
>   (Unauthorized)

On the client, I an populating both the User ID and the Auth Token:

```
this.client = new MobileServiceClient("https://mywebsite.azurewebsites.net");
var user = UserProfileService.GetCurrentSignedInUser();
client.CurrentUser = new MobileServiceUser(user.UserId.ToString())
{
    MobileServiceAuthenticationToken = user.AuthToken
};
```

And stepping through the code I have confirmed that the UserID matches that of the user and also the AuthToken is the same AutToken returned in my login method.

Is there something else I need to set/do to enabled authenticated requests to an Azure Mobile Service?

Thanks

**EDIT**
I have since disabled all other authentication providers in Azure but this hasn't solved the problem.
I have also debugged the code locally and the issue does not occur running on my localhost, only when deployed to Azure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your code, you are using custom authentication for your azure mobile app. As adrian hall's book about [Custom Authentication](https://adrianhall.github.io/develop-mobile-apps-with-csharp-and-azure/chapter2/custom/):

> You must turn on Authentication / Authorization in your App Service. Set the **Action to take when request is not authenticated** to **Allow Request (no action)** and do not configure any of the supported authentication providers.

Moreover, I would recommend you just use postman or fiddler to simulate the request against your api endpoint, you need to add a new `X-ZUMO-AUTH` header and set the value to `AuthToken` to narrow this issue. Also, you could check this issue on your local side, then simulate the request with the token to see whether your code could work on your side or this is the issue on azure side.  For your client, you could use `client.LoginAsync("custom", JObject.FromObject(user))` for logging without setting the `CurrentUser` by yourself. For more details, you could follow adrian hall's book to check this issue.

**UPDATE:**

According to your comments, I tested it on my side. I used the `UseAppServiceAuthentication` middleware both on my local side and azure side, and read the `SigningKey`, `ValidAudience`, `ValidIssuer` from my web.config under `Startup.MobileApp.cs` as follows:

```
//if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(settings.HostName))
{
    app.UseAppServiceAuthentication(new AppServiceAuthenticationOptions
    {
        // This middleware is intended to be used locally for debugging. By default, HostName will
        // only have a value when running in an App Service application.
        SigningKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SigningKey"],
        ValidAudiences = new[] { ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ValidAudience"] },
        ValidIssuers = new[] { ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ValidIssuer"] },
        TokenHandler = config.GetAppServiceTokenHandler()
    });
}
```

Note: I enable the Authentication / Authorization on azure. For my `CustomAuthController.cs` I called `AppServiceLoginHandler.CreateToken` with the setting from my web.config as the `UseAppServiceAuthentication` middleware initialized. Upon the settings, it could work as expected on my side and azure side.

Then I disable the `UseAppServiceAuthentication` middleware when deployed to azure side. I encountered the 401 as you mentioned, I assumed that the token validation may fail. I rechecked [Custom Authentication](https://adrianhall.github.io/develop-mobile-apps-with-csharp-and-azure/chapter2/custom/) and found that you need to init `SigningKey`, `ValidAudience`, `ValidIssuer` from the environment variables under your `CustomAuthController.cs` as follows:

```html
signingKey = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("WEBSITE_AUTH_SIGNING_KEY");
var website = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("WEBSITE_HOSTNAME");
audience = $"https://{website}/";
issuer = $"https://{website}/";
```

Use [jwt.io](https://jwt.io/) to decode the token, the `iss` and `aud` have changed, but I found it would still return 401. I noticed that we both set lifetime to `null` when invoke `AppServiceLoginHandler.CreateToken`. I tried to specific it with a value (e.g. TimeSpan.FromDays(30)), then it works on azure side.

In summary, this issue may due to the `lifetime` parameter value when invoke `AppServiceLoginHandler.CreateToken`, and you need to set a specific value instead of `null` on azure side. Moreover, you could add your issue [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-net-server/issues) for professional explanation.

Additionally, your mobile backend would use [AppServiceTokenHandler.cs](https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-net-server/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Server.Authentication/AppServiceTokenHandler.cs) for handling security token, you could override it and specific the `TokenHandler` parameter when using the `UseAppServiceAuthentication` middleware, then you could debug the token validation processing.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that I have turned on the Facebook authentication provider as my app also offers FB login. However, I can still log in using my custom auth, its just subsequent requests to the service that is failing. I've tried using fiddler and get the same {"message":"Authorization has been denied for this request."} response.

Comment: Your custom auth apicontroller can be accessed anonymously, while the controller for this issue has the `Authorize` attribute. You could try to remove the FB provider temporarily to narrow this issue. Also, please try to run your server side project on your local side, then try to check whether the custom authentication could work on your local side.

Comment: Hi Bruce, I've removed the FB provider and get the same result, 401 Unauthorized error. Is there a way to better understand WHY its Unauthorized?

Comment: I have also set up local debugging and I get no errors with Authentication, everything works fine.

Comment: According to your description, I did some test, you could refer to my update for more details.

Comment: Wow, you're right. Its the null value on the token lifespan! Thank you!  Also logged it on the azure-mobile-apps-net-server github issues log :)

Comment: @BruceChen we've got the exact same issue; however, we have lifespan set. Any idea what would be causing the issue besides lifespan?